# Query a table using conditions with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Hard to make a good title for this (feel free to edit), but hope it will make more sense ..
Say I have the following tables:

t1:

```
i1    v1
_________
1     bob
2     NULL
3     sam
4     NULL
5     kenny
5     NULL
```

t2:

```
i2     v2        item
______________
1      bob       prod_1
2      nick      prod_2
3      sam       prod_3
4      jj        prod_4
5      kenny     prod_5
5      cartman   prod_6
```

I need to JOIN the tables on `t2.i2 = t1.i1` but only where `t2.v2` does not exist in `t1.v1`. So I'm trying to get the following results:

Goal:

```
i2    v2      item
__________________
2     nick       prod_2
4     jj         prod_4
5     cartman    prod_6
```

This query below was my first attempt, and it's not working, so I'm trying to find a working and more efficient solution with JOINs.

```
SELECT * FROM t2
WHERE v2 NOT IN (
    SELECT v1 FROM t1 WHERE t2.i2 = t1.i1
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine, although I would use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT dm2.*
FROM web.delete_me2 dm2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM web.delete_me1 dm1 
                  WHERE dm2.some_int2 = dm1.some_int1 and dm2.some_var2 = dm1.some_var1
                 );
```

Although you can write this as a `join`, this version should be at least as good performance wise.  You want an index on `web.delete_me1(some_int1, some_var1)`.

Comment: Sorry, my "Goal" description/data was a little off what it should have been. Would you mind checking my edit?

Comment: @NickRolando . . . I based this answer on your query, and I think it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*, T2.* 
  FROM T1 
  JOIN T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
  LEFT JOIN T2 AS T2NO 
    ON T2NO.NAME = T1.NAME 
 WHERE T2NO.NAME IS NULL
```

or try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.* 
  FROM T2  
  JOIN T1
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
  LEFT JOIN T1 AS T1NO 
    ON T1NO.NAME = T2.NAME 
 WHERE T1NO.NAME IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` should be enough

```
select * From t2 
left join t1 on t2.i2 = t1.i1 and t1.v1= t2.v2 
where t1.i1 is null
```

Comment: I do not want to get results where t2.i2 does not join on t1.i1

Answer (score 0):

Do you need all records from `t2` where `i2` is in `t1` and `v2` is not?
If so, you can write this query

```
select * from t2 
where i2 in (select i1 from t1)
and v2 not in (select v1 from t1 where v1 is not null)
```

for `not in` to work as we need, `v1` shouldn't be `null`